# How to configure OpenApiRequestBody in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, openapi

I want to decorate my azure c# function with OpenApi annotations. The function accept JSON schema as parameters. How to mention that in the annotation.

Want to know how to configure below annotation

`[OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "json", bodyType: typeof(System.Text.Json.JsonDocument), Description = "Parameters",Example =typeof(Parameters))]`

```
public class ModifyOrder
    {
        [FunctionName("ModifyOrder")]
        [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "run", tags: new[] { "Modify Order" })]
        [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
        [OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "json", bodyType: typeof(System.Text.Json.JsonDocument), Description = "Parameters",Example =typeof(Parameters))]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "put", Route = null )] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string ordernumber;

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            ordernumber = data?.orderno;

            string responseMessage = $"Order:{ordernumber}";
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }

    }

    [OpenApiExample(typeof(Parameters))]
    public class Parameters 
    {
        /// <summary>The id of the customer in the context. This is also called payer, sub_account_id.</summary>
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("customerId", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>The order number. Used to uniquely identify a group of order lines.</summary>
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("orderNumber", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @SharpTooth's answer below is probably correct.  However, in `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi` v1.3.0, that feature is broken (look at https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-openapi-extension/issues/433).  The recommendation is to roll back to v1.2.0.  Unfortunately, that version has issues for us in another area (preventing our app from starting).  Oh well, waiting for v1.4.0...

Answer (score 10):

The main parameter of `OpenApiRequestBody` to focus on in your example is `bodyType`. Parameter `Example` can be omitted here and configured in a different way (explained later on). Instead of using `JsonDocument` rather use your `Parameters` class for the `bodyType` - this will then expose the characteristics of the `Parameters` class in the Swagger definition.

You can't use the `Parameters` class itself to represent a valid example and should instead create a dedicated class that inherits `OpenApiExample<T>` or in your case `OpenApiExample<Parameters>` then within this class override the `Build` method to construct your example instance of `Parameters`. You can then expose your example by decorating the Parameters class with the attribute `[OpenApiExample<T>]` (as you've done, but using an example class type!).

A couple of things worth noting about `OpenApiRequestBody` and this library more generally- the `Description` property of `OpenApiRequestBody` doesn't currently work as intended; the description text isn't rendered out in the Swagger `requestBody` definition. This leads on to my next point which is to note that (at the time of writing) this library - **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi** - is in a pre-release state (0.7.2) and accordingly does seem to contain some bugs, as I've discovered myself.

I've amended your `ModifyOrder` class below; this version I hope will help with answering your questions!

```
public static class ModifyOrder
{
    [FunctionName("ModifyOrder")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "run", tags: new[] { "Modify Order" })]
    [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
    [OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(Parameters), Description = "Parameters", Required = true)]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "PUT", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string ordernumber;

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        ordernumber = data?.orderno;

        string responseMessage = $"Order:{ordernumber}";
        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}

[OpenApiExample(typeof(ParametersExample))]
public class Parameters
{
    /// <summary>The id of the customer in the context. This is also called payer, sub_account_id.</summary>
    [OpenApiPropertyDescription("The id of the customer in the context. This is also called payer, sub_account_id.")]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("customerId", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>The order number. Used to uniquely identify a group of order lines.</summary>
    [OpenApiPropertyDescription("The order number. Used to uniquely identify a group of order lines.")]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("orderNumber", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ParametersExample : OpenApiExample<Parameters>
{
    public override IOpenApiExample<Parameters> Build(NamingStrategy namingStrategy = null)
    {
        this.Examples.Add(
            OpenApiExampleResolver.Resolve(
                "ParametersExample",
                new Parameters()
                {
                    CustomerId = "CUST12345",
                    OrderNumber = "ORD001"
                },
                namingStrategy
            ));

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems that in version 0.81 [OpenApiPropertyDescription()] is obsolete and we are supposed to use OpenApiProperty(object Default, string Description, bool Nullable).  This probably makes the Resolver obsolete too.  Problem is - it compiles but the Swagger.UI does not render, with an unspecified error.  Do you have a working example for the current preview?  Thanks!

Comment: @GilShalit thanks for pointing this out. I've created a new sample az function similar to my answer above, using version 0.9.0-preview (latest version I could find) and simply changed the OpenApiPropertyDescription attributes to OpenApiProperty as per your info, and it's all rendering properly in Swagger UI for me. I've pushed the sample to my own repo here for you to have a look- https://github.com/sharpt00th/dicey-az-func/ the solution is VS 2019.

Comment: Thanks @sharptoth - that works.  I was confused by the Default parameter of OpenApiProperty, thinking that is now used for the example value - obviously I was wrong - that is simply the default value...  It was late...

Comment: Great answer! Couldn't find this detail in the "official" docs